# Selenium to Heroku Python having an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to scrape data from Facebook using Selenium and it's working on localhost but not on Heroku when I upload it. Really it's taking too much time, the website is, https://facebookadsscraping.herokuapp.com/.

I have already added this added to the code, even Config Vars and BuildPacks.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), options=chrome_options)
```

The error:

```
2022-10-25T11:51:24.027410+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2022-10-25T11:51:24.030258+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2022-10-25T11:51:25.631546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-10-25T11:51:25.736717+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-10-25 11:51:25 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-10-25T11:51:25.736988+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-10-25 11:51:25 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2022-10-25T11:51:25.739868+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-10-25 11:51:25 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2022-10-25T11:51:26.040880+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-10-25 11:51:26 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-10-25T11:51:26.219134+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2022-10-26T01:33:56.960011+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2022-10-26T01:33:56.986001+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2022-10-26T01:34:11.653988+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app --timeout 10000`
2022-10-26T01:34:12.845203+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-10-26 01:34:12 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2022-10-26T01:34:12.845585+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-10-26 01:34:12 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:37788 (4)
2022-10-26T01:34:12.845628+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-10-26 01:34:12 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2022-10-26T01:34:12.850465+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-10-26 01:34:12 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2022-10-26T01:34:12.929647+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-10-26 01:34:12 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2022-10-26T01:34:13.348829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-10-26T01:34:19.583342+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=facebookadsscraping.herokuapp.com request_id=22ed3162-0818-4caa-a169-aa5c50831e92 fwd="45.123.222.156" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4539ms status=200 bytes=2251 protocol=https
2022-10-26T01:34:19.583416+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.3.208 - - [26/Oct/2022:01:34:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2096 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2022-10-26T01:34:22.139203+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=facebookadsscraping.herokuapp.com request_id=24d37e37-9243-4898-97c0-f5514d2192c6 fwd="45.123.222.156" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=368 protocol=https
2022-10-26T01:34:22.139275+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.3.208 - - [26/Oct/2022:01:34:22 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 207 "https://facebookadsscraping.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2022-10-26T01:36:38.836585+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/download" host=facebookadsscraping.herokuapp.com request_id=c1e64f5f-20af-4334-854e-eb0da25034cf fwd="45.123.222.156" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30002ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346862+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-10-26 01:37:11,345] ERROR in app: Exception on /download [POST]
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346877+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346878+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346879+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346881+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346881+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346881+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346882+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346882+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346882+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346883+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/user.py", line 67, in download
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346884+00:00 app[web.1]:     x.scrape_ads()
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346885+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/user.py", line 107, in scrape_ads
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346887+00:00 app[web.1]:     ads = self.driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='_8n_0').find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='_99s6')
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346887+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 856, in find_element
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346887+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346887+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346888+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346889+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346889+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346890+00:00 app[web.1]: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"._8n_0"}
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346890+00:00 app[web.1]:   (Session info: headless chrome=106.0.5249.119)
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346892+00:00 app[web.1]: Stacktrace:
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346893+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 0x55b1631572c3 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346893+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 0x55b162f6083a <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346893+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 0x55b162f99985 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346894+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 0x55b162f99b61 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346894+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 0x55b162fd1d14 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346894+00:00 app[web.1]: #5 0x55b162fb7f6d <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346894+00:00 app[web.1]: #6 0x55b162fcfa50 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346895+00:00 app[web.1]: #7 0x55b162fb7d63 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346895+00:00 app[web.1]: #8 0x55b162f8c7e3 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346895+00:00 app[web.1]: #9 0x55b162f8da21 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346895+00:00 app[web.1]: #10 0x55b1631a518e <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346896+00:00 app[web.1]: #11 0x55b1631a8622 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346896+00:00 app[web.1]: #12 0x55b16318baae <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346896+00:00 app[web.1]: #13 0x55b1631a92a3 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346897+00:00 app[web.1]: #14 0x55b16317fecf <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346897+00:00 app[web.1]: #15 0x55b1631c9588 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346897+00:00 app[web.1]: #16 0x55b1631c9706 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346897+00:00 app[web.1]: #17 0x55b1631e38b2 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346897+00:00 app[web.1]: #18 0x7f2c69ea8b43 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:11.346898+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-10-26T01:37:11.347783+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.16.4 - - [26/Oct/2022:01:37:11 +0000] "POST /download HTTP/1.1" 500 265 "https://facebookadsscraping.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2022-10-26T01:37:21.549082+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/download" host=facebookadsscraping.herokuapp.com request_id=3f0dbf50-8f37-4144-bcc5-09ce39fe3eb8 fwd="45.123.222.156" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813804+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-10-26 01:37:54,812] ERROR in app: Exception on /download [POST]
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813816+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813817+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813819+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813820+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813820+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813820+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813820+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813821+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813821+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813821+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/user.py", line 67, in download
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813822+00:00 app[web.1]:     x.scrape_ads()
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813822+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/user.py", line 107, in scrape_ads
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813822+00:00 app[web.1]:     ads = self.driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='_8n_0').find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='_99s6')
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813845+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 856, in find_element
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813845+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813845+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813845+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813846+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813846+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813847+00:00 app[web.1]: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"._8n_0"}
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813847+00:00 app[web.1]:   (Session info: headless chrome=106.0.5249.119)
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813848+00:00 app[web.1]: Stacktrace:
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813848+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 0x55fc133c32c3 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813848+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 0x55fc131cc83a <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813848+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 0x55fc13205985 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813849+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 0x55fc13205b61 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813849+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 0x55fc1323dd14 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813849+00:00 app[web.1]: #5 0x55fc13223f6d <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813849+00:00 app[web.1]: #6 0x55fc1323ba50 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813849+00:00 app[web.1]: #7 0x55fc13223d63 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813849+00:00 app[web.1]: #8 0x55fc131f87e3 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813850+00:00 app[web.1]: #9 0x55fc131f9a21 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813850+00:00 app[web.1]: #10 0x55fc1341118e <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813850+00:00 app[web.1]: #11 0x55fc13414622 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813850+00:00 app[web.1]: #12 0x55fc133f7aae <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813850+00:00 app[web.1]: #13 0x55fc134152a3 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813850+00:00 app[web.1]: #14 0x55fc133ebecf <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813850+00:00 app[web.1]: #15 0x55fc13435588 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813851+00:00 app[web.1]: #16 0x55fc13435706 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813851+00:00 app[web.1]: #17 0x55fc1344f8b2 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813851+00:00 app[web.1]: #18 0x7f1257d2ab43 <unknown>
2022-10-26T01:37:54.813851+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-10-26T01:37:54.814558+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.13.238 - - [26/Oct/2022:01:37:54 +0000] "POST /download HTTP/1.1" 500 265 "https://facebookadsscraping.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sir I am new here can you help me what should I actually provide

Comment: Please edit your question to copy-paste the full stack trace into a code block in the question.

Comment: Sir can you please check it now :)

Comment: Your code is failing because you tried to find an element that doesn't exist on the page. Based of off your error, no element has the class of `._8n_0`

Comment: but using the same code in localhost perfectly works for me. I am so confused sir

Comment: Post your complete code.